# RawJSON object in Json.NET

Tags: c#, json.net, json-rpc

I would like to deserialize a JSON-RPC request in two steps:

*Step 1:* Parse `id` and `method` into a base class
*Step 2:* Parse `params` into a second class depending on method

*Example:*

```
interface IAction
{
    bool Exec();
}

class Request
{
    [JsonProperty("method")]
    public string Method;

    [JsonProperty("params")]
    public RawJson Params;

    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public RawJson Id;
}

class Whisper : IAction
{
    [JsonProperty("to")]
    public string To;

    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public string Message;

    public bool Exec()
    {
        // Perform the whisper action
        return true;
    }
}

class Say : IAction
{
    [JsonProperty("msg")]
    public string Message;

    public bool Exec()
    {
        // Perform the say action
        return true;
    }

}
```

Code (if there were such an object as `RawJson`)

```
Request req = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Request>(s);
if( req.Method == "whisper" )
{
    Whisper whisper = RawJson.DeserializeObject<Whisper>();
    whisper.Exec();
}
```

One way to solve it would be if Json.NET has some kind of raw json object, but I can't find one.

So, have I just missed the raw object or is there another good way to do this?

---

Ps. The `id` value can be anything: null, string, int, array, etc. It should just be returned in the json-rpc response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dynamic`

```
dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(s)
if(dynJson.method=="whisper")
{
    var to = dynJson.@params.to; //since params is reserved word
}
```

This is also possible

```
string json = "{method:'whisper',params:{to:'aaa',msg:'msg1'}}";

var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json) as JObject;
if (jObj["method"].ToString() == "whisper")
{
    var whisper = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Whisper>(jObj["params"].ToString());
}
```

Comment: I would prefer to use a class because it will clarify the structure of the method params, and in addition I will be able to have methods to the class. (I will update my example). +1 because it is non the less a  working solution.

Comment: Neat! That seems to be more like what I am looking for. I will just try it out in my code.

Comment: It works as expected. I guess it requires me to deserialize-serialize-deserialize the params which is causing overhead. But if there is no other solution? Optimization will come later then. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ANisus In fact, it is `deserialize-deserialize`

Comment: So there is no serialization required for `ToString()` (stored string value)? If so, then it is very good. Two deserialize is what this solution should require in any case.

Comment: @ANisus Yes `ToString` doesn't involve reflection. Just *from internal representation to string.*